# Which UI element should I use to represent a sharing button on Android?

Tags: gui-design, android, mockup

I am trying to create UI mockups for an Android app. I need something like this:

[image: Android image]

I am using Justinmind prototyper free edition and I cannot find an UI element for the share button which produces the list of apps (as shown in the image). Is this a normal button or an image button or something else? Is there a tool which supports such an UI element?

Comment: Some good info about the share button from a design standpoint is here http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/share-button but I don't know how to get it to show up in Justinmind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think it is a native UI element. Try using a button with the image. Share icon is available from [The Share Icon](http://shareicons.com/). The Share Icon is free to use and it has a zipped package containing pixel based graphics in many sizes and vector graphics in .ai, .svg, and .eps formats. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

This UI element is known as the *Share Action Provider*, introduced in Android 4.0. It is described at [Android Design → Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html).

Although there isn't a pre-packaged stencil for this element at the moment, you can combine the popup menu and share icon stencils found at [Android Design → Downloads → Stencils and Sources](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html#stencils) for use in mockups.

Comment: On a related note, is there an officially recommended tool for Android UI mockups?

Comment: Not one that's officially recommended, but we provide stencils for OmniGraffle, Adobe Fireworks, and Adobe Photoshop.. you can also take the Fireworks PNG and use it with other tools.